How can I prevent login to office applications (office 2016) - or automatically log out after some time?
I have a shared workstation that is set to auto-log in and without getting into all those details the one issue with this configuration is if a user opens a word or excel document, it prompts for login to license the product with office 365.  If another user accesses the workstation, office is now signed in as them and I need to prevent this or auto log-out after an idle time.
The users do NOT need edit capability so word and excel can open in view only mode - if there were a way to force the office apps to always open in view only and not prompt for login that would be perfect.
Another option is if there is a way to associate office documents so they open in office online only.
